# Visual Basic excel macro - For cycle trouble

Tags: excel, vba

Im new to Visual Basic, and im trying to see if one value is not another value. This is my code:

```
For wasd = 1 To exemplo.Length
            If exemplo(wasd, 1) = cdia Then
                media_buffer(media_buffer.Lenght - 1) = exemplo(wasd, 13)
                ReDim Preserve media_buffer(media_buffer.Length + 1)
                cdia = exemplo(wasd, 1)
            Else If (exemplo(wasd,1) IsNot cdia) Then
            End If
        Next wasd
```

The problem is that it gives me an error here:

```
Else If (exemplo(wasd,1) IsNot cdia) Then
```

Im not sure that is the problem. I also have tried like this:

```
Else If exemplo(wasd,1) IsNot cdia Then
```

(without the () )
Well, i want to know why it give me a syntax error and what can i do to compare the two values?

Regardless, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong

```
Else If exemplo(wasd,1) IsNot cdia Then
```

Should be

```
ElseIf exemplo(wasd,1) <> cdia Then
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer (click the tick next to it) if it solves your problem

Comment: It says i need to wait 10 minutes @Tom